# Spark - How to import / export data to / from Hive table

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have data sitting in a Hive table that I'd like to import to Spark, score against a model object and then send the data back to Hive.  Is there a working example that shows how to do this?

Comment: You are way off. You don't import/export anything. Spark works on the Hive data using the Hive metastore. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - thank you - so I can't create an RDD from a sql-esque statement pointing to a hive table? ie `myRdd = sql('select * from myHiveTable'`)?

Comment: Read the link I gave you.